# Handle Records From DLQ In Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

We have a microservice that reads records from multiple Kafka topics. For each input topic, we have a separate **DLQ** topic to store records that could not be processed for whatever reason (non-valid record format, records could not be parsed using Avro scheme, could not connect to DB, could not call external microservice using REST API, etc).

Kafka **DLQ** topic content should be processed in the following ways:

1. The system tries to process events for three days at intervals: one
   hour after getting into **DLQ**, three hours, six hours, fifteen hours,
   twenty-four hours, and another twenty-four hours (1 + 2 + 6 + 14 + 24 + 24 = 72 hours).
2. If after three days the system could not process events, then the
   system stops trying to process them.
3. After three months after the last try, the system deletes events.

Is it possible to handle **DLQ** records in intervals as described in the first requirement?

If not what do you suggest to achieve the beforementioned requirements?

We use `spring-cloud-stream-kafka` for our microservice.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use [Polled Consumers](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.2.1/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#spring-cloud-streams-overview-using-polled-consumers) approach.
With regard to the complicated timing/scheduling schema you describe, it is something that you would have to implement.